# Term for second hand dealers

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a better term to describe second hand dealers (for electronic devices) and second hand dealers (for collecting newspapers and magazines for recycling)?

Comment: I am sure you really mean *dealer in second hand sth.* and not '2nd Hand Dealer', (which would mean the person dealing is a previously used sort, whatever that would be).

Comment: @JasperLoy: The OP did not use the term 'second hand'!

Comment: Please see my first comment above -- now it partly fails to make sense because of the edit.:(

Comment: No one uses newspapers or magazines intended for recycling for secondary sale, so there are no 'second-hand dealers' for such things. It's just recycling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Second hand" goods are goods that have been previously owned. In the USA, "used" is more frequently used.

If the goods are old enough and in good enough condition, they may be considered "antiques".

- USA: "Used car salesman"
- UK: "Second hand car salesman"

When these are sold in shops:

- USA: Thrift store
- UK: Second hand shop, junk shop, charity shop (when, as is often the case, the shop is run as a fundraising source for a charity)

There are also "antique shops" and "antique salesmen", if the goods are actually antique (although sometimes the definition is pushed somewhat).

In recent years, particularly for good quality second hand clothes of some age, the word "vintage" has come into use. "Vintage clothes shop", or just "vintage shop".

In the UK at least (and, to my knowledge, everywhere else) "second hand dealer" is not generally used when the goods are to be recycled (as opposed to re-used whole).

So, I would use "second hand dealer" to describe someone who buys and sells used electronic equipment.

I would not use "second hand dealer" to describe someone who buys and sells newspapers for recycling. Perhaps a "recyclable waste dealer", if they are selling on to whoever does the actual recycling.

Comment: +1 Nice one - clear and cut for the `recyclable waste dealer` for second hand dealers (for collecting newspapers and magazines for recycling)

Answer (score 1):

Second hand dealer is the best word that can be used in your scenario. The only other word that I can think of is:

Only thrift shop can be found in the dictionary

- thrift dealer = person that sells second hand goods.
- thrifter = a    person that buys goods in a second hand shop.
- [thrift shop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrift+shop) = where    people can purchase second hand goods.

I believe the best the word-choice for you is the one that you stated (second hand dealer), since there is no other synonym.

Comment: Is *second hand dealer* a standard term, other than as used by 'second hand dealers'?

Comment: Second hand dealer is a commonly known term for people who sell used goods. e.g used cars,clothes etc.

Comment: @Kris is that the question you intended to ask?

Comment: @slim: No, I asked if it is a *standard* term.

Comment: @Kris you asked "is x a standard term, other than when used as x". I'm not sure what you meant. Hopefully my answer below is sufficient.

Comment: slim, your answer is sufficient - probably, there are no better English term for second hand dealer (for electronic devices).